# If $E\subset \mathbb R^n$ measurable then $aE$ is measurable for all $a\in\mathbb R$ and $m(aE)=a^nm(E)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I want to show that if $E\subset \mathbb R^n$ is measurable then $aE$ is measurable for all $a\in\mathbb R$ and $m(aE)=a^nm(E)$. I don't really know how to do. Notice that $m$ is Lebesgue measure.

My idea was to consider the function $f(x)=ax$ ($a\neq 0$), then $f(E)=aE$ and since $f$ is bijective and $f^{-1}$ is measurable then $f(E)=aE$ is measurable. But my teacher told me that it doesn't work, and I don't understand why.

Comment: The canonical approach is to consider the measure $m'(E) = \lambda^{-n} m(\lambda E)$ and show it coincides with $m(E)$ on the Borel sets, and for this it suffices you do this on the intervals. This determines $m'$ uniquely to be $m$.

Comment: Boxes actually.

Comment: @Shalop Boxes are intervals under the lexicographical ordering. =)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: I don't think that is true. Consider lexicographic ordering on $\Bbb R^2$. Let $x = (1/3, 1/2)$, let $y=(2/3,1/2)$, and let $z = (1/2, 2)$. Then one has that $x<z<y$, but $x$ and $y$ are in $[0,1]^2$ while $z$ is not. So $[0,1]^2$ is not an interval in the lexicographic ordering.

Comment: Ah, I see what you meant. Lexicographic ordering on the box only, not on all of $\Bbb R^n$.